# How to copy conditionnal formating of a row to others rows in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Need some help. I'm currently making a Google Sheets, and I need some conditional formating. I need a row to be formatted with the condition on one of her cells.
For example, I need to formate A2:I2 with the formula =$H$2="No".
This was the easy part. I can do that.
The part that I fail is :
I have like 30 or 40 rows to formate like that, with the condition on the cell of the row. (H15 for A15:I15, H21 for A21:I21...). I tried to select the first row, copy it, and special past the formatting to another row, but Google makes some weird shit. It creates a new rule, but keep the previous cells range and add the currently selected. And the formula stays on the $H$2. I know it's because I put some $ in the name of the cell, but if I don't, it will not formating the entire row. Juste the first cell.

My question is :
How can I properly copy/paste the conditional formatting of the first row to the others one, with the condition correctly on the cell of each row, and keeping the formatting on the entire row?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the `$` sign is the following:

- `$H$2`: it will lock that cell only,
- `H$2`: it will lock that column,
- `$H2`: it will lock that row **(I think this is the one you are looking for)**,
  [image]

So you can set the range to be: `A2:I`

And the formula to be: `=$H2="No"`

Comment: Yep, I tried and I works. But in the range field, it keeps A16:I16 (the row I copy) and add A18:I18 (the row where I copy). Is there any risk of fail in some future, when I put more rules ?

Comment: the rules will be prioritized by order, so if the rule on top and below are true, then the only rule applied will be the rule on the top

Comment: Ho yes, I see. Thanks for the help ;)